# Update hyperlink on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a simple gallery for my site.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fdr6y6y7/

I have a large image that changes when you click a thumbnail underneath it.

However, I have an issue. Each 'large' image has a link to itself in a new window, however you can see that the original main image link never changes.

For example, if I click the 2nd thumbnail image the hyperlink inside the `largeimg` div should really change to http://placehold.it/250x250.

Can I use jQuery to do this?

```js
$('#thumb_scroll a').click(function(event){
    $('#largeimg img').attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    $('#largelink').attr("href", $(this).attr("rel"));
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="largeimg" class="largeimage">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/300x300" target="_blank" class="main"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></a>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="thumbouter">
    <div id="thumbnails">
        <div id="thumb_scroll">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to whoever updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fdr6y6y7/1/ :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Anon SO user for this: http://jsfiddle.net/fdr6y6y7/1/

```js
$('#thumb_scroll a').click(function(event) {
  $('#largeimg img').attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
  $('#largeimg a').attr("href", $(this).attr("href"));
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="largeimg" class="largeimage">
  <a href="http://placehold.it/300x300" target="_blank" class="main">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  </a>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="thumbouter">
  <div id="thumbnails">
    <div id="thumb_scroll">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="thumb">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="thumb">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I embedded the code in the answer, as link only answers are note well regarded on SO. They become useless when the link dies.

Comment: Another note: When you take someone elses solution you should mark the answer as "community wiki" (the small checkbox under the answer field).

Comment: Aaah - I didn't know that - thanks for letting me know :-)